# Lookup & Reference formula not working in excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, conditional-formatting

So I'm doing an excel project for fun. I am attempting to have columns M4 to O8 auto-fill with an N/A based on a selection from column E4 to E8, and to be left blank if the condition is false. With an If-then logic rule.

All columns involved are using a drop down from a custom list created on a second sheet labelled DATA ENTRY.

All tables are using text values.

I am currently receiving the error:

"The value you entered is not valid. A user has restricted values that can be entered into this cell"

I attempted to utilize Vlookup for the table within my logic formula but have never done that before, nor am I sure that it is the right method if what I am attempting is even possible.

Example of desired end result

| Rarity | Trait |
| --- | --- |
| :Common: | :N/A: |
| :Rare: | :{blank}: |

Sample of code I attempted:

'''

```
    =IF($E$4:$E$8="COMMON", VLOOKUP('Data Entry'!$A$7, Traits,'Data Entry'!$B$36, FALSE))
```

'''

I'm positive this is not the correct method at this point. I really would just prefer for the second column (which is a dropdown menu) to autofill with a selection from my data list based on the value placed in column one (which is also a dropdown list)

Comment: Sample data with the desired output would be useful here. Side note: [Conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) may not be what you are looking for

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you, you are correct. I actually just wanted to use a formula. However I do believe because I have the column set as a dropdown I am unable to do so. I tried it as a regular formula and received the message "The value you entered is not valid. A user has restricted values that can be entered into this cell".